# Can't set large json to Redis (Ubuntu Server)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, redis, node-redis

I have tried to store my json data in to redis database but it return

```
 events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write ECONNRESET
    at WriteWrap.onWriteComplete [as oncomplete] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:16)
Emitted 'error' event on RedisClient instance at:
    at RedisClient.on_error (\redis\index.js:342:14)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (\redis\index.js:223:14)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:315:20)
    at emitErrorNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:106:8)
    at emitErrorCloseNT (internal/streams/destroy.js:74:3)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: -4077,
  code: 'ECONNRESET',
  syscall: 'write'
}
```

But when I try to set the array of json with 3 objects. It worked

The large data is from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments

This is the whole code

```
    const redis = require("redis");

//NOTE: REDIS UBUNTU
    const redisClient = redis.createClient({
    url: "redis://ip:6379",
  
  }); 

//NOTE: REDIS DOCKER
//const redisClient = redis.createClient();

(async () => {
  //NOTE: BIG DATA
  let mockup = [] // data from https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments

  //NOTE: SET DATA
  redisClient.set("bigdata", JSON.stringify(mockup), (err, reply) => {
    console.log(reply);
  });

  //NOTE: GET DATA
  redisClient.get("bigdata", async (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
})();
```

I am not sure if I config something wrong in redis.conf file.

Comment: I think your problem here is that `get` and `set` are asynchronous functions; you call `set` but immediately `get` (i.e. your get operation doesn't wait for set to return a result); try moving the `get` operation into the `set` callback or just use async/await syntax to await the promise that each returns

Comment: @BrendanBond Thanks sir, I have tried to comment out the get section and add make set as the async function. I still get the same error

Comment: I wonder if the problem here is that the connection isn't opened? Node Redis will automatically buffer commands against closed connections and then send them once the connection is open. And it will attempt to open closed connections. Maybe the really big data creates a really big command that blows out a buffer or something?

Comment: Hi, All. I now could solve the problem. It is about the network connection. When I deploy my code to the real server. It works.